# Corrupted inflated view

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

Here is my scenario: In my application i have a Main activity, two fragments and a service that runs in background. I attach the fragments to my main activity using this piece of code:

```
        Fragment f1;
        f1=new loginfragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.frame,f1);
        ft.commit();
```

Which is working fine. one of these fragments contains a listview which is attached to an adapter.(i have verified that adapter is correctly attached to the listview and entries can be added to listview without any problems.
In order to be able to inflate a layout inside the listview adapter(which extends BaseAdapter) i created a constructor to feed Context to it.
background service checks a page periodically and sends the results to one of these fragments using an interface that the fragment implements(sending broadcasts didn't work for me).
interface is defined like this:

```
interface resultInterface{
   void receive(String s,Context con);
}
```

fragment implements the interface like this:

```
@Override
    public void receive(String s,Context con){
        String elements[]=s.split("<br>");
        if(elements.length>1) {
            if(elements[0].equals("REQUEST")) {
                init_notification("REQUEST",detect(elements[1],elements[2]));// a function that shows a notification
                item i = new item(elements[1], elements[2]);
                orders.add(i);
                adapter = new listview_adapter(orders,c);
                list.setAdapter(adapter);}
        }
    }
```

orders is an Arraylist and c is the context that is being passed to the listview adapter. service calls this interface method like this:

```
resultInterface resultinterface=new servefragment();
resulstinterface.receive(s,this);
```

upon receiving data (which results in calling the interface method) the fragment method is supposed to split the data and add entries to the listview.(i have verified that data is being correctly passed to the interface method.
BUT, the view that is being shown as listview entries is not correct( look corrupted somehow). Here is how it is supposed to look(using dummy data):[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ikfne.png) 
but here is how they are actually added(1 item is received from server which is correct but the layout is not): [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12UXd.png)

If you need more information just comment and i'll add them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the `Context` object your service is passing to you has a different theme than you're expecting. This can cause text colors, button colors, etc to all change.

> In order to be able to inflate a layout inside the listview adapter(which extends BaseAdapter) i created a constructor to feed Context to it.

Unless you need the `Context` instance somewhere other than inside `getView()`, you don't have to pass a `Context` via a constructor. Here's the full signature of the `getView()` method:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

The `parent` argument is guaranteed to be non-null, and all `View` instances have a `getContext()` method, so you can always retrieve a `Context` by writing `parent.getContext()`. Additionally, this will be your **Activity** (as opposed to something like your Application), which has the added benefit of having the correct theme.

So delete all of the code that passes the `Context` into your adapter and just use `parent.getContext()` instead, and I bet the problem goes away.